# How can I get a string value from URL?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

My url is `http://localhost:4200/#/home/jobmanager/status`

How do I get "status" in string format? I'm using TypeScript (.ts file)

EXAMPLE:

```
this.getJobs("HERE");
```

WHERE "HERE" IS THE STATUS SET

Comment: Are you making any API call?

Comment: update your question with routing module

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include *any* attempt at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to try to solve your own problem first, as your attempts help us to better understand what *you* want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information,  see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 1):

Use `ActivatedRoute` like this =>

`this.activatedRoute.pathFromRoot[2].url.subscribe(mySegment=> console.log(mySegment[0].path));`

`pathFromRoot` let you pick the segment you want from all the URL, you just need to set the segment you want inside `[]`

Answer (score 0):

Other way could be

```
constructor(private router: Router){
  let data = this.router.url;
  let guid = (data.substring(data.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, data.length));
}
```